# What old version of Windows provides out-of-the-box DVD movie playback?

Tags: video, windows, disk-drive

I bought a Playstation 2 in 2000, which famously included a DVD drive capable of playing DVD movies. I wanted the same movie playback capability on my Windows 98 PC.

As I recall, I mistakenly thought this would mostly be a matter of just upgrading my PC's optical drive to a DVD-ROM. I did so, but never had working DVD video playback. I don't recall whether it was an issue of my PC specs, or needing some additional hardware or software for video decoding. I never upgraded beyond Windows 98 and switched to a PowerPC Mac around 2005, which by then had DVD playback out-of-box.

I'm sure there must have been a moment when PC & video card specs and Windows software (ME?, XP?) came into alignment for easy DVD playback on most Windows PCs. And I do recall there was a brief craze over "Home Theater PC's" (HTPC) in the early 2000's. Now, I am thinking about accessing this feature on a retro PC.

Which version of Windows first supported DVD movie playback out-of-box, using what included playback software, and with what required PC specifications?

Answer (score 6):

The first version of Windows to support out-of-the-box DVD playback is Windows XP Media Centre Edition*, which was created specifically to target the HTPC fad that you mention, and it also has some special [hardware requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP_editions#Hardware_requirements).

The only mainstream versions of Windows to play DVDs without additional software were Windows Vista Home Premium and Ultimate, and Windows 7**.

---

* ["Windows XP Media Center Edition is distinguished with its exclusive component, Media Center, a media player that supports watching and recording TV programs, as well as playing DVD-Video"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP_Media_Center_Edition)

** ["MPEG-2 and Dolby Digital (AC-3) decoders were included beginning with Windows Media Player 11 on Windows Vista (Home Premium and Ultimate editions only)."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Player); ["Unfortunately, the Windows Media Player program doesn't support DVDs in Windows 8 and 10"](https://www.wikihow.com/Play-DVDs-on-Windows-Media-Player)

Comment: It all came down to the license fees.  Microsoft was loathe to pay $$$ on a _per-copy_ basis.

Comment: Yeah, from what I can make out Microsoft intended DVD drive vendors to license and supply the codecs, which Media Player would then be able to use to provide a full regular DVD player. Though I'm pretty sure my final PC, of about that vintage, just came with PowerDVD, a third-party player.

Comment: Surprising answer. I thought it would have been part of some standard/common Windows version or upgrade, rather than so "niche" in the early 2000s, at least.

Comment: @davidbak Lol at "loathe to pay $$$ on a per-copy basis", since that was __Microsoft's business model__.

Comment: @BrianH - yup - money was supposed to flow in one direction only!

Comment: It's also why the Windows world was given Arial if memory serves: it has very close to the same metrics as Helvetica, then the default Postscript font, but Microsoft were able to purchase it outright rather than license it.

Comment: Its the same reason the original XBox couldn't play DVDs without buying the remote.  They didn't want to pay for the codec licenses for every single XBox, so instead the licenses where tied to the remote / IR receiver dongle.

Comment: @BrianH Microsoft would pass that cost onto you. Would you want to pay for DVD player licenses for all your office computers?

Comment: This probably do not count but just had to comment :) Toshiba Tecra 750 Dvd Laptop did it out of the box, but with extra hardware & software included in Windows 95. Very picky dvd playback to work in newer Os. Very expensive also.